# A rhopalic sentence of at-least 5 words, beginning with as long word as possible

Tags: wordplay, english, open-ended

Rhopalic sentences are sentences which have words whose length is one more than the previous word. eg:

- > I do not hunt birds.
- > I do not know where family doctors acquired illegibly perplexing handwriting; nevertheless, extraordinary pharmaceutical intellectuality, counterbalancing indecipherability, transcendentalizes intercommunication's incomprehensibleness.

These sentences begin with `I` whose length is 1. The next word is of 2 letters, and so on.

Your challenge is to create a rhopalic sentence which has at-least 5 words, and begins with a word which is as long as possible. eg:

- > Yes, they drink orange extract.

(This was the best I could think of.)

---

- Proper nouns are **not** allowed.
- The words should be listed on dictionary.com
- The sentence should make sense.

Comment: How do you count  's, don't ... ?

Comment: `'`s are not counted. Any piece of punctuation is not counted. So `don't` is of 4 letters.

Comment: Should the sentence "make sense" as a *clause* or as an entire *sentence*?

Comment: Unless you define precisely what you mean by "make sense", I'm voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: "Counterbalancing indecipherability transcendentalizes intercommunication's incomprehensibleness."  starts at 16 :)

Comment: @Deusovi "make sense" means that it is a **complete and meaningful English sentence.**

Comment: And **grammatically correct** too.

Comment: _Yes, they drink orange extract_ Was the best you could think of? But you already wrote _Doctors acquired illegibly perplexing handwriting; nevertheless, extraordinary pharmaceutical intellectuality, counterbalancing indecipherability, transcendentalizes intercommunication's incomprehensibleness._ which starts with length 7 :)

Comment: Not enough rep to answer, but here's an alliterative one: Self-satisfied superciliously, sesquipedalians superspecialized subclassification.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi: You've just restated the problem. Define "meaningful". Is "colorless green ideas sleep furiously" a 'meaningful' sentence? If not, where's the precise boundary?

Comment: @oerkelens - you overlooked the obvious _"Extraordinary pharmaceutical intellectuality, counterbalancing indecipherability, transcendentalizes intercommunication's incomprehensibleness."_ - it scores a respectable 13

Comment: @oerkelens I didn't write that. This is a very famous sentence.

Comment: @Deusovi No, that is not meaningful. "Colourless" and "Green". No. Certainly not.

Comment: You can start at "intellectuality" for the longest starting word; no need to include the shorter "extraordinary pharmaceutical". Alternatively, just remove the comma and have "Indecipherability transcendentalizes intercommunication's incomprehensibleness.".

Comment: @IanMacDonald You have a valid sentence starting with 17 letters... and it was already in the question itself :)

Comment: @Hackerdarshi: "Meaningful" is inherently subjective. Unless you provide a precise definition of "meaningful" for this question, the question is too broad.

Comment: Do hyphens count to the character count or not?

Comment: @SMSvonderTann No.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 34):

7 words, starting at 14 letters, ending at 20:

> Anticapitalist
>  circumnavigator
>  underrepresented
>  unsophisticatedly
>  noninterventionist
>  greatgranddaughters,
>  uncharacteristically.

You’d have thought this old left-winger would be supportive of his descendants’ views — but apparently not.

Comment: This could be 6 words starting at 15 letters.  I'm not sure which is better for the challenge.

Comment: @dan1111: right, I wondered about that too.  The OP phrased the headline as “beginning with as long a word as possible”, so taking that literally, the 16–20 version would be better than the 15–20 one.  But I feel it would be more natural to say that the *longest* word (i.e. the last word) is the main criterion, and then the starting point should be a tie-breaker when the longest words are equal, with longer sentences being better.  So (describing sentences by their first and last word lengths) I’d rank 14–19 < 15–20 < 14–20 < 17–21, and I gave the version of mine that I think is best :-)

Answer (score 26):

Starting at 11 characters going to 19:

> "Dreadnought increasingly misrepresents battlecruiser's transformations," overapprehensive commanders-in-chief unenthusiastically counterdemonstrate.

Comment: misrepresent has only 12 characters and not the needed 13

Comment: @Frozn Oops, I thought I counted 13 there. Fixed it anyways.

Answer (score 19):

Starter for 8

> Brothers embracing solidarity demonstrate sectarianism

Comment: Solidarity means unity/harmony... Sectarianism is hatred. How can brothers who embrace solidarity demonstrate sectarianism?

Comment: Solidarity (which is not specifically harmony) with each other, sectarianism (which is not specifically hatred) against others. Real-world solidarity often involves opposition to some other group, in fact. But this is a puzzle site, not a political one :-)

Answer (score 12):

How about 7 characters:

> Finally somebody destroyed ridiculous helicopters.

**Update**

And how about 10 characters:

> Cappuccino plantations declassified extraordinary specifications.

And now even 11 characters:

> Permanently accomplished extraordinary underestimated generalizations!

Answer (score 11):

Nineteen.

> Congregationalist's counterintelligence uncharacteristically electroencephalograms counterrevolutionaries

could this be classified as torture?

the challenge seems to be to download the largest word list and sort it by length....

Comment: Very nice, but if we’re being persnickety about following dictionary.com, *electroencephalogram* is only listed there as a noun, not a verb as you use here.

Answer (score 10):

My contribution:

> Rhopalic disasters calculably deemphasize predicaments.

Answer (score 5):

5 words, starts with 5 letters:

> Learn pieces without advanced polyphony.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a long one:

> Everyone excitedly overthrows liquidizing puzzleheaded aerodynamic anagrammatical overcapitalized hyperventilating neuropathological electrophysiologic comprehensivenesses

Starts at 8, goes up to 19. Total of 12 words.

Answer (score 2):

Starting at 18 letters in the first word, and has 5 words, ultimately ending at 22 letters in the last word.

> Disenfranchisement electromagnetically overenthusiastically clinicopathologically [countercountermeasures](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjO4oS4hpbNAhXHSyYKHbEpCngQFggjMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wiktionary.org%2Fwiki%2Fcountercountermeasure&usg=AFQjCNGTq-zKDKy5M30vj_hbe5PueC3eDQ&sig2=OX9amjoLkhtjeKcrLzO0rg).

This one is the highest as of now. *(that is grammatically correct)*

For `countermeasures`, technically `countermeasures` and `measures` are correct as verbs so `countercountermeasures` should be correct.

Comment: `countercountermeasures` can't be assumed, in my opinion. Words like `greatgrandfather` and `demisemiquaver` illustrate the preference to use prefix variations in these sort of built-up words. However the internet  is on your side, although it also supports my own preferred `anticountermeasures`. I don't think either word gets enough "air time" to have the real weight of English-speaking opinion make a final judgement.

Answer (score 1):

5 words starting with 18 letters

> Paleoclimatologies characterologically, overenthusiastically, overintellectualizes contemporaneousnesses.

Comment: See... that's why I asked if it should be a grammatically correct sentence. (noun/verb agreement)

Comment: Chowzen is not an English teacher.

Comment: @Chowzen What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Peanut I was just saying that "Paleoclimatologies" is plural, therefore the verb would be  "overintellectualize," not "overintellectualizes."

Comment: @Chowzen, I meant "Chowzen is not an English teacher."

Comment: @Peanut I had been harping over whether or not the answers should be grammatically correct, and was merely pointing out that, even though I was doing this, I am not an English teacher.

Comment: @Chowzen, why did you mention yourself? Couldn't you just say "I am not an English teacher"?

Comment: @Peanut It's a literary mechanism known as "referring to yourself in the third person." It creates the illusion that a narrator is commenting about the speaker. It is sometimes used in chat rooms and chat boxes in games. For instance, I could say "I think this game is *terribly so much fun!!!*" after losing a game, followed by "Chowzen sounds sarcastic." It's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Chowzen Is there a full name for this?

Comment: That's actually not rhopalic:  18, 19, 20, 20, 21

Answer (score 1):

> Abdominohysterectomy counterdemonstrations spectrophotometrically photoheterotrophically paraskevidekatriaphobias.

20 letters in the first word, with five words in total, going up to 24 letters in the last word.

Comment: What's the verb in this sentence?

Comment: "paraskevidekatriaphobias"

Comment: Every reference I've found to "paraskevidekatriaphobia(s)" says it's a noun, not a verb.

Comment: Even if it were a verb, it doesn't agree with the subject.  It would have to be "counterdemonstration**s** ... paraskevidekatriaphobia" or "counterdemonstraion ... paraskevidekatriaphobia**s**".

Answer (score 1):

Start with 2 letters, 6 words. (I fixed it.)

> No one will treat lemons sweetly.

Start with 6 letters, 4 words.

> WARNING: Contents Extremely Precarious

Okay, is this acceptable? 3 letters, 5 words.

> The café never serves samples.

And *another* one! (3 letters, 5 words.)

> Can this dream become reality?

Comment: Both are unacceptable. The first one uses a proper noun and the second one is only of 4 words. Nevertheless, good try.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi I'm really young and I tried my best.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ones that are not as long as others, but still would count.

- This one starts with 8 letters, has 9 words total, ends in a 16 letter word, and is alliteration all the way through:

> Actually, abandoned abacterial abiological ablutophobes accommodating accompaniments adrenalectomize acousticophobics.

- Another one sharing most words with the previous rhopalic sentence that starts with 9 letters, has 8 words, and ends in a 15 letter word:

> Yesterday abacterial abiological ablutophobes accommodating accompaniments adrenalectomize acousticophobics.

- Here's another derviration of the first rhopalic sentence that actually mentions rhopalic sentences itself. Starts with 8 letters and has 9 words total, ending in a 16 letter word.

> Rhopalic sentences abbreviate abiological ablutophobes accommodating accompaniments adrenalectomize acousticophobics.

Comment: alliteration tornado